# Sorting rows by matching values in two different columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have to look through my worksheet to find duplicate entries on the basis of two columns - column A and column D. If entries under both these columns match in any two given rows, then I consider them duplicated. In order to do this, I have been trying to sort the rows such that rows with matching entries under column A and column D appear one below the other. For example, if I have:

Col A Col B Col C Col D

ABC   PQR   123  456

ABC   XYZ   789  006

ABC   BNM   376  456

ABC   QWR   387  006

Preferably through VBA, I want to be able to put it in the format:

Col A Col B Col C Col D

ABC   PQR   123  456

ABC   BNM   376  456

ABC   XYZ   789  006

ABC   QWR   387  006

I am aware of how to sort by one column but not sure if there is a way to do it by two. There are more than 5000 rows in the worksheet and more than 50 columns and  I would like to be able to sort these quickly for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel has built-in functions to help you with the issue (no VBA required).

Select the cells including your data and navigate to "Data - Sort & Filter - Sort". There you can add different levels of sorting (e.g. sort by Col A first, then by Col B, ...).

If the duplicates need to be removed this can be done directly as well. Select the cells including your data and navigate to "Data - Data Tools - Remove Duplicates".  You can select the columns which need to match in order for Excel to remove the duplicates.

Comment: This works - thank you! As for the duplicates, I do not need to remove them. I need to merge the rows that match keeping only the unique values.

Comment: This is exactly what the remove duplicates function does. One unique row will remain and only the duplicate "versions" of it will be removed.

Comment: I don't think I understand - the remove duplicates function compares all cells in two rows, combines the unique values, and deletes the "duplicate" row? When I was previously using this function, I don't think I came across this. To be clear, I need to be able to merge the two rows if two of the fields match and in some cases, one of the rows will have data in columns that the other row will not.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In case one of the rows will have data in columns that the other row will not the "remove duplicates" function will probably not be helpfull. It is used to remove cells where all columns match but does not merge information in the way I now (hopefully) understand you are looking for.